# Showing checkbox inside input field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display a datepicker with the option to disable its input field. When "Never Expire" is selected like image below datepicker input field will be disabled

[image]

This is what I have done so far:

```html
<style>
.chkbox {
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
<input type="text" placeholder="&#xf073; Select Date" id="datepicker" autocomplete="new-datepicker" name="expireDate" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" />
```

Here are my questions:

1. How can I add the "Never Expire" checkbox at right side of Date Picker input field?
2. How can I disable datepicker input field when the "Never Expire" option is checked?
3. How do I submit the only one option either datepicker or checkbox value?

Thanks in anticipation :)

Comment: Selected option means the checkbox value or the select date, or both?

Comment: Put padding-right in the input and move the checkbox with absolute positioning

Comment: @DavidLiang Selected mean checkbox option because on checkbox selected option datepicker will be disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like the idea of using absolute positioning to move the checkbox into date picker input. I thought this is a good candidate for using [Bootstrap input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/input-group/).

```html
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date-select-with-expire-option">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control date-input" name="SelectedDate"
                   placeholder="Select date" />
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text">              
                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                            class="custom-control-input expire-option"
                            name="DateNeverExpires" id="never-expired">
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="never-expired">
                            Never expires
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It would look like the following by default:

[image]

Then you can play around CSS/SASS to make it look like what you want:

```
.input-group.date-select-with-expire-option {
    .input-group-text {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    
    // Just in case there are multiple .form-control elements
    .form-control {
        // Set the first .form-control's left border color to transparent
        &:first-of-type {
            border-left-color: transparent;
        }
        
        // Set the last .form-control's right border-color to transparent
        &:last-of-type {
            border-right-color: transparent;
        }
    }
    
    .input-group-prepend {
        .input-group-text {
            border-right-color: transparent;
        }
    }
    
    .input-group-append {
        .input-group-text {
            border-left-color: transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

It would look like:

[image]

To disable date picker input field when the "Never expire" option is checked, you can write up some jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.date-select-with-expire-option .expire-option[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
        console.info($(this));
        let $dateInput = $('.date-select-with-expire-option').find('.date-input');
        $dateInput.prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

When the checkbox is checked, it would look like

[image]

I would submit both of them, and you can run the logic in your application to determine which values to use. Just make sure they have the name attribute set in the input elements.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/thbfnd2s/38/

#### Update: install Date Range Picker

I am just throwing in another example of using [Date Range Picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) as the implementation of the date picker for the date input.

You can easily select the date input by referencing its class, or Id if you want:

```js
function() {
    $('.date-select-with-expire-option .date-input').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true
    });

    ...
}
```

[image]

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/thbfnd2s/42/

#### Update: install jQuery Date Picker

It looks like the author has problems using jQuery date picker so let me show what it needs. You need to install

- jQuery UI: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js
- jQuery UI base CSS: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Then what you need to change is just the piece of code that instantiates the date picker object:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.date-select-with-expire-option .date-input').datepicker();
    
    ...
});
```

[image]

[image]

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/thbfnd2s/43/

Comment: @freedomn-m: what did you mean? Which part of my solution is using absolute positioning?? I would love to learn.

Comment: Open the fiddle, select the checkbox, inspect element, select the input type=checkbox, css:  `.custom-control-input { position: absolute }`  - it's not important, but the bootstrap UI does a lot of relative (and some minor absolute) positioning.

Comment: @freedomn-m: Oh that custom control input. It's directly from Bootstrap framework and I didn't write a single line of code of it. I was just saying I don't like using absolute positioning if I have to write my own code (in this case, moving the checkbox into the date input). I am sure the framework uses absolute positioning in many places, but if I have to develop custom codes, I would avoid using that as much as possible. Not saying it's bad. It's just my preference. :)

Comment: Right, makes more sense.  Completely agree - use something that someone else has fully tested for you.

Comment: @David Liang Thanks for your reply. There is one little problem that id="datepicker". I mean now its not showing date calender

Comment: @Murteza: I didn't implement any date calendar. I thought your problem was about putting the checkbox along with the date input. Your OP didn't show which implementation of date picker you're using either. There are lots of them out there: jQuery datepicker, Bootstrap calendar, Date Range Picker, etc.

Comment: @DavidLiang I am using jQuery datepicker and if you please see I have `id="datepicker"` in my code.

Comment: @Murteza: I've updated my answer and showed you how to do it using Date Range picker, but the process is really the same as with other pickers: you can add the id back to the date input, or you can reference it via class, like how I did. Please read my codes and understand how it works. I am not trying to completely build a solution exactly like yours, but hoping you understand the concepts behind it.

Comment: @DavidLiang I am thankful to you to give me your precious time. I appreciate!! I used in my whole project jQuery date picker and at this stage its very hard to change this utility to  "Date Range Picer". Please help me with jQuery date picker. I tried my best by deeply studying your code but still unable to disable it. Please check this and correct me to disable date input: https://jsfiddle.net/Raakh5/cm2L15ob/10/

Comment: @Murteza: please see my updates. You just swap the code that instantiates the date range picker to jQuery date picker. I am not sure why you're having issues. If you have to use `#datepicker` as the ID of the date input, you need to change the code `let $dateInput = $('.disable-date-input').find('.date-input');` to use that ID instead, something like `let $dateInput = $('#datepicker');`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put both inputs (checkbox and date picker) on a div (as a wrapper)
after that give absolute position to the checkbox. you can align it with margin syntax.

Comment: I placed both checkbox and datepicker in one div wrapper but still they are displaying separately. I used this css to align `.chkbox { padding-right: 10px; font-weight: bold; position: absolute}`

Comment: Relevant: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)  - please *demonstrate* how to do this in your answer.

Comment: @Ali Safaei I updated my question. can you please jsFidle example